# Does the Jenkins server do the build or off load the work?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I thoughts that a common / usual mode of operation for a Jenkins server, which runs as the "jenkins" user, is to use a plugin (such as SVN) to notice that the code changed, check-out the code, then build the code.

I was told (by our admins) that Jenkins should be configured so that it does NOT do the actual build, but rather, it simply calls another computer to do the work.

This came up because I work in a controlled environment and the jenkins user does not have privileges that it requires to issue certain commands (docker, singularity, etc). The "proper" way to handle this was to have the jenkins server remotely connect to an external computer as a user that has all appropriate permissions and then do all the work on a different computer.

I really do not want to write scripts that probe the source control to see if something changed before deciding to do work, or not do work. It also means that I no longer have the ability to simply go to the Jenkins server and look at the build output to see what the specific errors are.

Comment: At my company, the jenkins machines do the work. If you are working with github or any other popular scm, you shouldn't have prob to check for changes. Most have robust api's where they will call an end point when a changes is detected. Whether that be a pull request is made, commit is made, a merge done etc.

Comment: Currently using SVN, will be using "gitLab" in the immediate future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on "Distributed builds" on the Jenkins wiki:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

The Jenkins master will poll your version control system (svn or git) and once it finds a new commit start a build on either itself or another computer/agent/"slave".

Comment: I configured credentials to hit git (in our latest environment) as well as users with SSH keys to connect to slave servers to off load the work of building and deploying as desired.